50s B&W sci-fi movie about an alien(s) that was eventually killed by cars' headlights
I remember just a few parts of this movie that scared the bejeezus out of me as a kid.  I last saw it again on TV probably 20 years later (about 35 years ago.)  I swore I would remember the name of the movie, but alas no.  I would love to see it again.
I remember this alien creature attacking and drinking the blood of cattle.  The end was when the people were about to encircle it and kill it by turning on all of their headlights.  This movie had such a great impact to me as a kid and probably got me interested in UFOs/UAPh.  Please help me ID this creepy and impactful movie.

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Given that the movie is from the 1950s, and that the climax involves encircling the alien and killing it with the light from car headlights, this could well be Invasion of the Saucer Men (1957). From the summary on wikipedia:

A flying saucer lands in the woods. A teenage couple, Johnny Carter and Joan Hayden, while driving to their local lover's lane without the headlights on, accidentally run down one of the little green men from the saucer.

One of the hands of the dead alien detaches itself from the body, and runs amok in the woods, including killing a cow - this is possibly the "cattle blood-drinking incident" that the OP mentions. The army is called in, but:

In the end, it is the teenagers, not the military, who defeat the aliens when they discover that the saucer's occupants cannot stand the glare from their car's bright headlights. When the teenagers all flash their headlights on them at once, the three remaining aliens disappear in a puff of smoke.


Good thing soldiers never use any bright lights at night or anything!

@Adamant but don't soldiers try to sneak around at night (so they won't be targets)?  After all, that's why there are blackout lights on Jeeps, etc.

@RonJohn - That depends on whether they are on a stealth mission against a superior force, or trying to show themselves to be the superior force. I figure the latter is much more likely for soldiers blowing up a single UFO in their own country.

@Adamant even in the 1950s Army, you didn’t think you were superior to unknown.  (Doesn’t make for good movies, though.)

ubiquitous non-ionizing EM radiation: my one weakness. "oh what a world"

@Adamant You show a light at night, you reveal your location and thus make yourself a target.  Thus even the superior force will not show light if they can help it--although they might do so indirectly via star shells.  (Very bright flares on parachutes, fired by artillery.)

You might be thinking about The Eye Creatures. It was a comedy/horror movie from 1967.
I don't remember any scene with killing cattle, but the car light scene is prominent.
In the story a UFO lands and one of the aliens gets run over by a car. The rest of the aliens terrorise the neighbourhood looking for revenge.

The aliens are vulnerable to light so in the end the teenagers surround them with their cars and turn on the headlights, making the creatures explode.


Worth noting that this is a made-for-TV colour remake of the B&W film in the other (current) answer.
